# zero sets of fundamental vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Let M be a compact manifold on wich acts a torus T. Denote $M^T$ the invariant subset of M by the action of T.

Let F be a submanifold of $M^T$. Denote N the normal bundle of $M^T$ in M restricted to F.

Let $X \in \mathfrak{t}=Lie(T) $. Denote $ M(X_{|M})$, the zero set in M of the fundamental vector field of X, and denote by $ N(X_{|N})$ the zero set in N of the fundamental vector field of X.

Why this implication is true:

$N(X_{|N})\neq F \Rightarrow $ the inclusion $M^T \subset M(X_{|M})$ is strict  ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a question from a textbook?

Comment: Actually, I'm reading an article and it was not possible for me to write the exact question since this will require a lot of stuff ! But the data I gave in my post is all that needed to deduce the claim in the article

Comment: Well it would make sense to add a link to the article ...